# Node.js - Listening for system process

Tags: node.js, process, discord

I'm looking for a way to detect when a specific process start on my computer using node.js.

I want something like discord does : when I start a game, I want my application to detect that game.

I searched in the child_process environment and the Discord API but I didn't find anything exploitable

Comment: check this. this might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar

Comment: Yeah indeed i'll try it, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar):

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

// Initialize watcher.
const watcher = chokidar.watch('path/to/folder', { persistent: true });
 
// Add event listeners.
watcher
  .on('add', path => log(`File ${path} has been added`))
  .on('change', path => log(`File ${path} has been changed`))
  .on('unlink', path => log(`File ${path} has been removed`));
 
// More possible events.
watcher
  .on('addDir', path => log(`Directory ${path} has been added`))
  .on('unlinkDir', path => log(`Directory ${path} has been removed`))
  .on('error', error => log(`Watcher error: ${error}`))
  .on('ready', () => log('Initial scan complete. Ready for changes'))
```

Comment: I tried chokidar but I couldn't find an event that is trigger when I start the application (i.e: event when starting chrome.exe)